# Use Vertigo Slide.Show 2 control in a Silverlight Navigation Application

Tags: silverlight, slide.show2

In a Silverlight Navigation Application (VS2010 project) I need to have slideshow functionality. I have found Vertigo's Slide.Show 2 control (http://www.codeplex.com/SlideShow2) which is great but I can't figure out how to use it inside a canvas within my application. I am a beginner when it comes to Silverlight, so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The component you're looking at comes as a precompiled silverlight application that you just include in an HTML page and configure to get it working the way you want. If you want to get it onto a canvas inside your own silverlight app, you will need to crack open the source code and pull out the libraries needed for the component.

If you take a look at the [Page.xaml](http://slideshow2.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/27061#149067) file included in the source, you will see that the xmlns "v" is bound to `Vertigo.SlideShow.Controls` in the `Vertigo.SlideShow` assembly. The rest of the xaml in that file can then be used to create a canvas that hosts the slide show control:

```
<Canvas x:Name="SlideShowRoot">
    <Canvas Name="mediaRoot" />
    <v:SlideDescription x:Name="slideDescription" Opacity="0" />
    <v:NavigationTray x:Name="navigationTray" MouseEnter="navigationTray_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="navigationTray_MouseLeave" Opacity="0" />
    <v:EmbedViewer x:Name="EmbedViewerElement" />
</Canvas>
```

Once you have that sorted, turn your attention to the [page's code-behind file](http://slideshow2.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/27061#149066) which contains a ton of event wire-up code that is probably needed to get the control working.